# SendKeys.Send and turning off key modifiers

Tags: c#, keyboard, sendkeys

I want to make ^N work the same as Down arrow in a tree control. I thought
I'd just have to add the following to the KeyDown handler:

```
SendKeys.Send("{Down}");
```

but this gets treated as a Control-Down arrow since the control key
is currently pressed. The [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx)
describes how to turn on the 
control modifier but not how to turn it off.

Thanks,
Keith

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to come late to the party but I think I found a solution:

First, import SetKeyboardState:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);
```

Then, just call it with a zeroed byte array before calling SendKeys.Send():

```
SetKeyboardState(new byte[256]);
SendKeys.Send("your key sequence");
```

That worked for me. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can p/invoke to keybd_event. That will let you simulate a key being both in "up" and "down" state.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the hard way of doing it. I admit this is not the optimal way to do it. I'm sure you already know this. You might want to overload the WindProc method of the control & use SendMsg Win32 Api. This is how I used get things to work back in the day.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to wait until the control key is no longer pressed and only then `KeySend`, e.g.:

```
while (System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
{
    // lets try again after a while
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
}
SendKeys.Send("{Down}");
```